# Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'end_time' at row 1

Tags: java, android, json

From android , I am hitting a web-service . The JSON includes two fields such as **startTime & endTime**. In DTO classes (both client & server side),  the type of startTime & endTime  is Long. Also, in database table, the type is int(11) .

I am capturing the startTime  & endTime as ,

```
 Date startDate = new Date();
    Long startTime = new Long(startDate.getTime());
    mDto.setStartTime(startTime);


 Date endDate = new Date();
        Long endTime = new Long(endDate.getTime());
        mDto.setEndTime(endTime);
```

But, I am getting the value of JSON is  ,

```
{
....
"startTime":1484630553565,
 "endTime":1484630653424,
....
}
```

So, How to truncate the these fields..?

Comment: whats wrong with `System.out.println(new Date (1484630553565L));`

Comment: I am not printing the Date Value. I am capturing Date value and sending it in Long format through JSON

Comment: unclear what you are asking.  Are you saying that these Dates will not fit into `int(11)` ?

Comment: Yeah. I should truncate it.

Comment: these values contain milliseconds, whereas unix dates only contain seconds.  If you can not increase your columns size then divide by 1000 to make them unix dates

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.getTime() in java returns milli-seconds, and they do not fit in int type in mysql.

Use seconds: `new Date()/1000`

Note: from_unixtime() etc. methods in mysql works with seconds so that's the way to go regardless of this issue.

Comment: yep, as per my comment +1

Comment: @Y.E.  Thank you for the solution. I got the fields truncated.